# z3 minimum Visual Studio compiler version

Tags: z3

What is the minimum Visual Studio compiler that can be used to build z3?  I have tried commit 2d2ec385410a133bfb8c699d1c2c85fcf141f4b8 from github, and it fails to build with both MSVC 2008 and 2010.  We need it to work with MSVC 2008, but using that compiler to build resulted in a failure when trying to convert a const_iterator type to an iterator type.  So I tried with MSVC 2010 and got this:

..\src\util\hwf.cpp(320) : error C3861: '_mm_fmadd_sd': identifier not found

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Both, Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 are not supported anymore, by Z3 but also by the rest of Microsoft (mainstream support has ended earlier this year, see [Support Lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Visual%20Studio%202010&Filter=FilterNO)).

`_mm_fmadd_sd` is an intrinsic for floating-point fused-multiply-and, which is definitely available in VS 2010 and we built Z3 using VS 2010 for a very long time, so that can't be the problem. For some reason your header files don't contain that function declaration, or the compiler macros are set up incorrectly. Definitely make sure you're running the compilation in a VS2010 command prompt and that you're not using the Express edition (at the very least it doesn't come with OpenMP and possibly some other extensions as well).

Comment: I think the fused multiply add problem might be due to using the 32 bit compilers. Not sure if that instruction is for x64 chips.

IN any case, we need 32 bit Visual Studio 2008 builds.

Thanks for the response, Christoper (Chris?).

Comment: The actual assembly instruction for fused-multiply-add is only available on itanium and in SSE5(6?), not on x86 or amd64, but if the compiler macros are correct, then they should select whatever is available on your platform. We have stopped supporting VS2008 a long time ago, it's very well possible that doesn't work and I don't even have a copy installed that I could try it with; definitely try to get it working in VS2010 before you do anything else.

Comment: Some things to check: Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010), do not use anything that says "cross" or "x64". Use a 32-bit python to run scripts/mk_make.py, otherwise you will most definitely run into problems later. Do not use -x when running python scripts/mk_make.py

Comment: I was able to get it working with 2012.  I think this will be fine, we'll just have to spawn z3.exe to do the calculations instead of using the API.  Reason being is we can't mix and match 2008 and 2012 run time in our application - bad things happen when one does that.

Comment: That's great, thanks for letting us know! You're right, it shouldn't make any different if you're just spawning off the .exe. The only thing you may need at some point are the VS2012 VC runtime DLLs, they are usually found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist

Comment: I have the same problem using VS2013. Exactly the same. And I can't compile it when creating the VS_PROJ but I can compile when using nmake from the command line. Why is that? @ChristophWintersteiger

Comment: @user1618465: No idea. What is your setup? Note that any version of VS can also use old VS toolsets if they are installed, check that you're indeed compiling with the latest toolset.